# How to delete any filed in ViewSet

Tags: django-rest-framework

```
class DepartSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    attrs = AttrSerializer(source="depattr", many=True)

    people = PeopleSerializer(source='perdepart', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Departs
        fields = ('url', 'name', 'describe', 'pinyin', 'attrs', 'people')

 class DepartsViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):

    """
    i want delete people field in List , and Retain people fieled in retrieve.
    """

    queryset = Departs.objects.filter(disabled=False).order_by('-uptime')

    serializer_class = DepartSerializer
```

1.I  want the result like this:
2.get /depart

```
[ 
{"name":"depart1","id":1},
{"name":"depart2","id":2},
]
```

3.get /depart/1

```
{
    "name": "depart1",
    "id": 1,
    "people": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "per1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "per2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use different serializers in your viewset depending on the action by overriding the viewset's `get_serializer_class`:

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.action == 'retrieve':
        return DepartSerializerWithoutPeople
    return DepartSerializer
```

`retrieve` is the action called by `get /depart/1/`. And then you can define your `DepartSerializerWithoutPeople` like this:

```
class DepartSerializerWithoutPeople(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    attrs = AttrSerializer(source="depattr", many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Departs
        fields = ('url', 'name', 'describe', 'pinyin', 'attrs',)
```